# Storing tinyint values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two input fields where a user can enter a name of a person and then choose their role, `faculty` or `instructor`. For the roles I am using `tinyint` to determine whether it is true or false (`0` or `1`).  I am having difficulties saving the values to mysql db. When submitting the query nothing is being stored. [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/test2.php)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);


$person1_role1 = empty($_POST['role1'][1]) ? 0 : 1;

$person2_role2 = empty($_POST['role2'][1]) ? 0 : 1;

$person_name1 = $_POST['person_name1'];
$person_name2 = $_POST['person_name2'];

$option = $_POST['role'];

if($option == 'faculty'){
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO person (contact_role, person_name) VALUES ($person1_role1, $person_name1)");
} elseif ($option == 'instructor') {
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO person (instructor_role, person_name) VALUES ($person2_role2, $person_name2)");
}

print_r($_POST);

}

?>
<form action="test2.php" method="POST">
<b>Select the role for the person</b>
</br>
</br>
Name:<input type="text" name="person_name1">
     <input type="checkbox" name="role1[]" value="faculty">faculty
     <input type="checkbox" name="role1[]" value="instructor">instructor<br><br>
Name:<input type="text" name="person_name2">
     <input type="checkbox" name="role2[]" value="faculty">faculty
     <input type="checkbox" name="role2[]" value="instructor">instructor<br><br>

<input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">

</form>
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `faculty_role` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `instructor_role` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `person_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`person_id`),
);
```

Comment: Why are you using checkboxes if a person can have only one role? Why not a `<select>` or `<input type="radio" />`. And you're using `$_POST['role']` but as you can see in your `print_r($_POST)` that key doesn't exists.

Comment: @Petervanderwal a person can have both roles

Comment: Then is neither 0 or 1

Comment: @davidstrachan can it be 1, 1 if the person is both `faculty` or `instructor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `$option = $_POST['role']` but 'role' isn't in your POST-data, see your `print_r($_POST)`. So `$option` is neither 'faculty' nor 'instructor' so none of your INSERT-queries is being called.

You say a person can have both roles, but you use two INSERT-queries. Thats odd. Following would make more sense:

```
$person1_faculty = in_array($_POST['role1'], 'faculty') ? 1 : 0;
$person1_instructor = in_array($_POST['role1'], 'instructor') ? 1 : 0;
$person1_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['person_name1']);
mysqli_query(
    $con,
    "INSERT INTO person (faculty_role, instructor_role, person_name) VALUES " .
    "(" . $person1_faculty . ", " . $person1_instructor . ", '" . $person1_name . "')"
);
```

Your $_POST['role1'] is a array, check with [in_array](http://php.net/in_array) if faculty and/or instructor are in it. And use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to prevent SQL-injection.

Comment: +1 Oh Alright I see, How can I make `$option = $_POST['role']` part of the post?

Comment: Check edited answer. You don't add 'role' to your $_POST-data but you should rebuild your PHP-logic. Besides that, start with adding a single user, with a single role (I think that's already difficult enough for you), if that works start expanding your code. Take small steps ;)

Comment: ALright, I made the changes but nothing is being inserted. Yes, you are right, once i get this working I will need to go back and work on my php logic.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Got a small error in building the query (happens when you're used to an different db-technique at work). Change `", " . $person1_name . ")"` to `", '" . $person1_name . "')"`.